# How to block ads on etsy with Greasemonkey?

Tags: ads, greasemonkey, adblock

I'm trying to block ads on etsy, because they make it hard to search for items to buy, and I found that the class of the ads always start with "js-merch-stash-check-listing v2-listing-card"

My attempt:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Etsy Ad blocker
// @description Etsy Ad blocker
// @include     https://*.etsy.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

$(".js-merch-stash-check-listing v2-listing-card*").hide()
```

Please help.

Comment: Why not use AdBlock (e.g. uBlock Origin)?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples that you can work on:
**Note:** Using the more robust `@match` instead of `@include`

#### Using JavaScript to remove items

This way items gets removed at the time the script runs but new items are not affected.
**Note:** Using pure JavaScript without the need for additional library.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Etsy Ad blocker
// @description     Etsy Ad blocker
// @match           https://*.etsy.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

document.querySelectorAll('.js-merch-stash-check-listing.v2-listing-card').forEach(item => 
                item.style.display = 'none');
```

#### Using CSS to remove items

CSS rules remain active and apply to items created after as well, therefore it is recommended.
**Note:** **Greasemonkey 4** doesn't support `GM.addStyle/GM_addStyle`.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Etsy Ad blocker
// @description     Etsy Ad blocker
// @match           https://*.etsy.com/*
// @run-at          document-start
// ==/UserScript==

const node = document.createElement('style');
node.textContent = 
`.js-merch-stash-check-listing.v2-listing-card {
  display: none;
}`;
(document.head || document.body).appendChild(node);
```

With **Violentmonkey**, **Tampermonkey**, **FireMonkey**, or **Greasemonkey 3** you can use `GM_addStyle`.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Etsy Ad blocker
// @description     Etsy Ad blocker
// @match           https://*.etsy.com/*
// @run-at          document-start
// @grant           GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle(
`.js-merch-stash-check-listing.v2-listing-card {
  display: none;
}`);
```

With **FireMonkey**, you can also use *UserCSS* more efficiently.

```css
/*
==UserCSS==
@name            Etsy Ad blocker
@description     Etsy Ad blocker
@match           https://*.etsy.com/*
==/UserCSS==
*/

.js-merch-stash-check-listing.v2-listing-card {
  display: none;
}
```